# Using datetick with keepticks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, matlab-figure

I'd like to display an array at length (24*60*60). The x axis is the time of a day.

When I use the following code, x axis shows `00:00:00, 00:59:59, 01:59:59, ..., 23:59:59`, but there is no plot on the figure. That is `plot(1:length(A),A)` has no effect. (I also tried turning on/off `hold` switch, and `24`/`24+1`)

```
A = rand(1,86400);
x0 = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:SS');
x1 = datenum('23:59:59','HH:MM:SS');
xData = linspace(x0,x1,24+1);
plot(1:length(A),A);
set(gca,'XTick',xData);
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS','keepticks');
```

When I try the following code, plot can be displayed properly. However, the x axis becomes `00:00:00, 02:24:00, 04:48:00, ..., 21:36:00, 00:00:00`

```
A = rand(1,86400);
x0 = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:SS');
x1 = datenum('23:59:59','HH:MM:SS');
xData = linspace(x0,x1,86400);
plot(xData,A);
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS','keepticks');
```

I also tried this version

```
A = rand(1,86400);
x0 = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:SS');
x1 = datenum('23:59:59','HH:MM:SS');
xData = linspace(x0,x1,86400+1);
plot(xData,[A,0]);
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS','keepticks');
```

The x axis is still `00:00:00, 02:24:00, 04:48:00, ..., 21:36:00, 00:00:00`, and the plot can be displayed normally.

Is there any way to set the x axis to become `00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, ..., 23:00:00, 00:00:00` or `00:00:00, 00:59:59, 01:59:59, ..., 23:59:59`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from first plotting on the interval `[1,numel(A)]` and then setting the ticks at `[xData(1),xData(end)]`.

You can fix this by plotting `A` within the range of `xData`:

```
A = rand(1,86400);
x0 = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:SS');
x1 = datenum('23:59:59','HH:MM:SS');
xData = linspace(x0,x1,24+1);
plot(linspace(x0,x1,numel(A)),A);     % change here
set(gca,'XTick',xData);
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS','keepticks');
```

Also, adding the line

```
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',45); % or some angle
```

improves the readability of the tick labels.